# Child/Parent event raising

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

I have a parent abstract class with several children classes. Eventually, I would like the progress done in the children classes to be shown via a progress bar in the GUI.

What I currently have done right now, which I am realizing will not work, is the event method definition declared in the parent class as a virtual method which each child class will overwrite. So something like :

```
public abstract class Parent
{
 public event EventHandler someEvent;

 protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          EventHandler eh= someEvent;
        if (eh!= null)
        {
            eh(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my child classes have something like :

```
  protected override void OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSomeEvent(sender, e);
    }
```

and the event is raised somewhere in the child class.

However, seeing as the parent class is abstract, I will not be able to listen to the event from my GUI because I can not create an instance of an abstract class.

Am I completely off course and/or is there another method of doing this?

Comment: Why can't your UI attach to the event on the child instance? If you inherit from `Parent`, `Child` will have the event, too.

Comment: The idea is that I don't necessarily want the GUI to know which child raised the event. @SpikeX

Comment: So you want a static event handler on Parent, that only has one instance, is what you're saying.

Comment: I want a progress bar for each child so your solution was just right @SpikeX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# : accessing parent class's events not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742214/c-sharp-accessing-parent-classs-events-not-possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach to the event from the child instance.

```
public abstract class Parent
{
      public event Action Something;

      public void OnSomething()
      {
          if (Something != null)
          {
              Something();
          }
      }
}
public class Child : Parent
{

}

Child c = new Child();
c.Something += () => Console.WriteLine("Got event from child");
c.OnSomething();
> Got event from child
```

You can even declare it as a `Parent` type that contains a child:

```
Parent c2 = new Child();
c2.Something += () => Console.WriteLine("Got event from Parent type");
c2.OnSomething();
> Got event from Parent type
```

An abstract class is just a code template that gets copied into every class that inherits from it (to put it simply). Think of it like, all of your `Child` classes contain an identical copy of the code that exists in `Parent`.

---

Note that this will also produce a unique event handler for each instance of `Child`. Having a static event handler for all `Child`s that derive from `Parent` would look like this, and requires no code in `Child`:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public static event Action Something;

    public static void OnSomething()
    {
        if (Something != null)
        {
            Something();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could do something like this, for example:

```
Parent.Something += () => Console.WriteLine("This will be invoked twice.");

Child c = new Child();
Child c2 = new Child();
c.OnSomething();
c2.OnSomething();

> This will be invoked twice.
> This will be invoked twice.
```

Both of those objects/event calls will invoke the same event handler even though they come from separate children.

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your implementation of OnSomething() in the child class?

Comment: @moalaz There isn't one. It inherits from `Parent` automatically. You can invoke `OnSomething();` from within `Child`, unless you specifically want to override it with another behavior, but by default, it will just invoke the `Something` event.

Comment: @moalaz I also added some code for a static event if you didn't want the event handler to be unique to each `Child` instance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to not, because `someEvent` does not specify `static`, every instance of the child class will have its own `someEvent`. This means you aren't getting a unified view, but a diversified one. This is useful for responding to a button being pressed, since you don't want to respond the same way when they click the background.

Typically rather than using a class hierarchy, you would use composition to handle this kind of situation. For example, adding the following class to yours:

```
public class ParentContainer
{
    private List<Parent> watched = new List<Parent>();
    public void Add(Parent watch)
    {
        watched.Add(watch);
        watch.SomeEvent += Handler;
    }

    private void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```