# How to fire the ObjectDataSource's Inserting event programmatically (as opposed to DataBound Control)

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I have a wizard control that collects data over 7 steps. There's a ObjectDataSource at the 7th step. When the user clicks the finish button, I want the ObjectDataSource Control to fire its Inserting event so that data can be passed to the underline method and eventualy be saved to the database.

How do I do that?

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="UploadPhotoObjectDataSource" runat="server"
 DataObjectTypeName = "PhotoData" TypeName = "ImagesBLL.cs" 
 InsertMethod = "AddImage">

</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can according to this thread:

[Why events can't be used in the same way in derived classes as in the base class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253757/why-events-cant-be-used-in-the-same-way-in-derived-classes-as-in-the-base-class)

Triggering the Inserting event instead of doing an actual insert is a step you may wish to reconsider.  Calling Insert will trigger then Inserting event (and after the data is inserted, the Inserted event).