# Xamarin camera access in a shared project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mobile

I'm building a shared project and I want to access the camera. For now i'm just trying to get this to work on android.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207571/camera-access-with-xamarin-forms) here in stackoverflow and it works but I'm not being able to put this to work in my project becouse I want to call the camera in a **ContentPage** and not in my Class App : Application.

Comment: That would still work.  You just put a button on your Page that calls the App.Instance.ShouldTakePicture() method

Comment: I tried this:
`Command = new Command(o => App.Instance.ShouldTakePicture())`
But i'm getting an error "The event 'MyNameSpace.App.ShouldTakePicture' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'MyNameSpace.App')"

Comment: I make it work after watching [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253757/why-events-cant-be-used-in-the-same-way-in-derived-classes-as-in-the-base-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this library for that: http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile