# How to call button event handler on validation when I have two buttons?

Tags: c#

Here is the thing. I have two buttons on my form. One is buttonAccept, the other one is buttonClose. I have problem with validation because I don't know how to set condition in code. Here is the code:

```
private void txtValue_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string ext = txtValue.Text.Trim();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ext))
        {
            //doSomething
        }
        else 
        {
            if(buttonAccept.Click ??)
            {
                buttonAccept_Click(sender, e);
            }
            else buttonClose_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

When I type code like this:

```
private void txtValue_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string ext = txtValue.Text.Trim();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ext))
        {
            //doSomething
        }
        else 
        {
            buttonAccept_Click(sender,e)
        }
    }
```

the program will(ofcourse) call only Accept button even if I clicked on Close.

I hope that somebody will know the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to understand what's ur actual question. Please provide more information or try to change ur wording.

Comment: What are you trying to do there? ``if(buttonAccept.Click ??) ...`` is not valid c# syntax...

Comment: If you are trying to perform a *null check* on ``buttonAccept.Click``, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253757/why-events-cant-be-used-in-the-same-way-in-derived-classes-as-in-the-base-class) is related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don´t you validate the textbox after the user clicked the Accept button? 
Then you don´t have to mess with the Close button or invoke event callbacks directly in your code.

Comment: Well, you helped me. The solution is that I don't need else at all. Without else, he will just checked if text box is valid and when I click on Accept and it is not valid he will give me some message. When is valid, he will just do what it takes. When I clicked on Close, the form will close. Very simple.  Thank you man! ;-)

Comment: You´re welcome. Please mark the question as answered to help people who have the same problem.