# Adding and removing events in one method, c#

Tags: c#, events

Sometimes I need to add and remove events from bunch of controls. And I always do that with one method for adding events:

```
private void AddEvents(){
    textBox.TextChanged += TextChanged;
    integerUpDown.ValueChanged += ValueChanged;
    colorPicker.SelectedColorChanged += ColorChanged;
    //... and so on
}
```

And same one for removing events:

```
private void RemoveEvents(){
    textBox.TextChanged -= TextChanged;
    integerUpDown.ValueChanged -= ValueChanged;
    colorPicker.SelectedColorChanged -= ColorChanged;
    //... and so on
}
```

I'm using different types of controls and different types of EventArgs. I'd like to compress it to one method, something like:

```
private void RemoveEvents(bool add){
    textBox.TextChanged add ? += : -= TextChanged;
    integerUpDown.ValueChanged add ? += : -= ValueChanged;
    //or method approach
    ManageEvent(colorPicker.SelectedColorChanged, ColorChanged, add);
    //... and so on
}
```

But that's not possible with ? operator. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I thought for a minute that you might be able to use [`MulitcastDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx) directly, but it seems that they are not mutable. So while you could use it, you couldn't use it directly with C# events I believe.

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253757/why-events-cant-be-used-in-the-same-way-in-derived-classes-as-in-the-base-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to avoid having to specify both adding and removing a handler, there is only reflection left.

```
private static void ManageEvent(object target, string evnt, EventHandler handler, bool add)
{
    var ei = target.GetType().GetEvent(evnt);
    if(add)
    {
        ei.AddEventHandler(target, handler);
    }else{
        ei.RemoveEventHandler(target, handler);
    }
}
```

This method finds the target event info on a given instance, and based on a condition invokes either the add or remove method. You can also make this generic, but then you would have to specify the type of the delegate. This assumes *EventHandler*, which is quite common.

```
ManageEvent(textBox, "TextChanged", TextChanged, add);
```

In C# 6, you can also use `nameof(textBox.TextChanged)` instead of `"TextChanged"` which makes your code easier to refactor.

Please note that reflection performs mostly slow, so consider using the approach shown in other answers if you have to call this method a lot.

This all is necessary because the events are located in another class, and you cannot thus access directly their backing field. However, if the event is located in your class, you can pass it as a reference to a similar helper method:

```
private static void ManageEvent<TDel>(ref TDel source, TDel value, bool add) where TDel : class
{
    if(add)
    {
        source = (TDel)(object)Delegate.Combine((Delegate)(object)source, (Delegate)(object)value);
    }else{
        source = (TDel)(object)Delegate.Remove((Delegate)(object)source, (Delegate)(object)value);
    }
}
```

This does exactly what normal event methods do, either combine or remove events.

```
ManageEvent(ref MyEvent, MyEventHandler, add);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is neat.

First, define the following interface and class:

```
public interface IEventHolder
{
    void Attach();
    void Detach();
}

public class EventHolder<H> : IEventHolder
{
    private Action<H> _add;
    private Action<H> _remove;
    private H _handler;

    public EventHolder(Action<H> add, Action<H> remove, H handler)
    {
        _add = add;
        _remove = remove;
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void Attach() { _add(_handler); }

    public void Detach() { _remove(_handler); }
}
```

Now you can define this private field:

```
    private List<IEventHolder> _eventHolders = new List<IEventHolder>();
```

In the `Form_Load` event I've written this code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _eventHolders.Add(new EventHolder<EventHandler>(h => textBox1.TextChanged += h, h => textBox1.TextChanged -= h, textBox1_TextChanged));
        _eventHolders.Add(new EventHolder<EventHandler>(h => numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += h, h => numericUpDown1.ValueChanged -= h, numericUpDown1_ValueChanged));
        _eventHolders.Add(new EventHolder<MouseEventHandler>(h => textBox2.MouseMove += h, h => textBox2.MouseMove -= h, textBox2_MouseMove));

        _eventHolders.ForEach(eh => eh.Attach());
    }
```

Notice that the line `_eventHolders.ForEach(eh => eh.Attach());` attaches all events.

My handlers look like this:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = numericUpDown1.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void textBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _eventHolders.ForEach(eh => eh.Detach());
    }
```

The `textBox2_MouseMove` handler detaches all of the events in one go.

I've tested this and it works like a treat.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It looks like there isn't an easy non-duplicit solution without Reflection. Is it necessary for EventHolder to be a generic class? Isn't EventHandler enough general?

Comment: @Korhak - The generic is so that it can hold different event handler types. Your code showed you needed that. In my example I showed `MouseEventHandler` as an example. Nonetheless, I think my solution is easy and it doesn't use reflection. It nicely bundles most of the code into class so that there's really only 6 lines of code in your actual form.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operation returns a value based on the statement's result. Returning "+=" is definitely not valid, since you are basically subscribing to the event. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

However, why don't you take the simpler approach?

```
private void AddOrRemoveEvents(bool add)
{
    if (add)
    {
        AddEvents();
    }
    else 
    {
        RemoveEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: With the conditional operator approach I was just showing just how would I like it to be, not that it should work. The purpose of this topic is to add just one line of code with one new event. In your solution I still have to add handling the adding and removing the event in each of them, which I want to evade.

Answer (score 1):

One line if statement to the rescue! There will be a little bit of repetition but none the less it is a one liner

`if (add) textbox.TextChanged += TextChanged; else textbox.TextChanged -= TextChanged;`